# Running regression to analyse how leverage changes around

Tags: regression, leverage, abnormal-returns

I am running a single variable regression with BHAR returns as independent variable and Leverage as dependent variable.

I would like to analyse does the leverage 1 year prior to IPO and 1 year after the IPO have correlation with BHAR returns.

What is the best way to do this? Running two different regressions or what

Comment: Why would you run regressions instead of directly applying correlation tools (e.g. Bravais-Pearson)?